# How can I do the same thing on the other side of the page

Tags: html, text, html-table

my code is here I want to put another quote on the opposite side(for example on the left ) pls help me as fast as posible

```
<div style="display: table;background-color:#d4af37; padding:20px;
    color:white; width: 200px; height:170px;x;  border-radius:50px">
        <p style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
            <b>“I intend to leave after my death a large fund for the 
            promotion of the peace idea, but I am skeptical as to its 
            results.”</b>- <em>Alfred Nobel </em>
```

P.S I posted the code in the coments I am not sure when this site compiles code and when not sorry I am  new

Comment: <div style="display: table;background-color:#d4af37; padding:20px; color:white; width: 200px; height:170px;x;  border-radius:50px">
<p style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;"><b>“I intend to leave after my death a large fund for the promotion of the peace idea, but I am skeptical as to its results.”</b>- <em>Alfred Nobel </em>

Comment: You can delete your comment with the code it is not needed; you just have to format the code in your question - indent 4 spaces.

Comment: Your html is incomplete. You can try using float left and right.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do the same thing that you have already on the other side of the page like you're asking, you would first need to close your `<p>` tag with the corresponding closing tag `</p>`, and the same with your `<div>` tag, add a closing `</div>`. Remove the typo of `x;` then set another style property and value of `float:left;` to your `<div>` element.

Once that's done you can copy the entire div code, paste below it and change `float:left;` to `float:right;`

I have included a complete snippet for you to please try, which does all of the above. (it would replace the code you have included in your question)

Happy coding :)

```html
<div style="float:left; display:table; background-color:#d4af37; padding:20px; color:white; width:200px; height:170px; border-radius:50px">
  <p style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;"><b>“I intend to leave after my death a large fund for the promotion of the peace idea, but I am skeptical as to its results.”</b>- <em>Alfred Nobel </em></p>
</div>
<div style="float:right; display:table; background-color:#d4af37; padding:20px; color:white; width:200px; height:170px; border-radius:50px">
  <p style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;"><b>“I intend to leave after my death a large fund for the promotion of the peace idea, but I am skeptical as to its results.”</b>- <em>Alfred Nobel </em></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to place items next to each other. If you have quotes, use the [q element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/q) for short inline quotes or the [blockquote element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blockquote) for longer quotes:

```css
.quotes {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.quote {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  background-color: #d4af37;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

q {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="quotes">
  <div class="quote">
    <q>I intend to leave after my death a large fund for the promotion of the peace idea, but I am skeptical as to its results.</q> - <em>Alfred Nobel </em>
  </div>
  <div class="quote">
    <q>Don't believe everything you read on the internet.</q> - <em>Abraham Lincolm</em>
  </div>
</div>
```